# How to trigger form field validators inside a modal in Ant Design?

Tags: reactjs, antd

Sorry if the title is misleading or the solution is clear and I'm just not seeing it or this question has been asked alredy, I didn't find the answer (I'm posting this question at the end of my work day).

Anyway, I have a form inside a modal, using AntD components and I've defined the modal and the form like this:

```
<StyleImports.AddColumnDetailsModal
            open={columnDetailsModalOpen}
            centered={true}
            onCancel={() => {
                setColumnDetailsModalOpen(false);
            }}
            destroyOnClose={true}
            maskClosable={false}
            title={JsonImports.reports.subPages.preliminaryLimits.addColumn.detailsModal.title}
            footer={[
                <Button 
                    key='saveColumn' 
                    type='primary' 
                    onClick={() => {
                        form.submit();
                        setColumnDetailsModalOpen(false);
                    }}
                    htmlType={'submit'}
                >
                  {JsonImports.reports.subPages.preliminaryLimits.addColumn.detailsModal.buttons.save}
                </Button>,
                <Button key='closeModal' type='default' onClick={() => {
                    form.resetFields();
                    setColumnDetailsModalOpen(false);
                }}>
                    {JsonImports.reports.subPages.preliminaryLimits.addColumn.detailsModal.buttons.cancel}
                </Button>
            ]}
        >
            <div>
                <Form
                    layout={'vertical'}
                    onFinish={handleFormFinish}
                    form={form}
                >
                    <Form.Item
                        label={JsonImports.reports.subPages.preliminaryLimits.addColumn.detailsModal.form.columnName.label}
                        name={'columnName'}
                        rules={[
                            {
                                required: true,
                                message: JsonImports.reports.subPages.preliminaryLimits.addColumn.detailsModal.form.columnName.missingInput
                            }
                        ]}
                    >
                        <Input.TextArea
                            ref={columnNameRef}
                            rows={6}
                            placeholder={JsonImports.reports.subPages.preliminaryLimits.addColumn.detailsModal.form.columnName.placeholder}
                        />                            
                    </Form.Item>
                    <Form.Item
                        label={JsonImports.reports.subPages.preliminaryLimits.addColumn.detailsModal.form.columnType.label}
                        name={'columnType'}
                        rules={[
                            {
                                required: true,
                                message: JsonImports.reports.subPages.preliminaryLimits.addColumn.detailsModal.form.columnType.missingInput
                            }
                        ]}
                        validateFirst={true}
                    >
                        <Select
                            placeholder={JsonImports.reports.subPages.preliminaryLimits.addColumn.detailsModal.form.columnType.placeholder}
                            options={columnTypes.map(type => ({label: type.title, value: type.key}))}
                            onSelect={handleTypeSelect}
                            value={columnTypeValue}
                            ref={columnTypeRef}
                        />
                    </Form.Item>
                </Form>
            </div>
        </StyleImports.AddColumnDetailsModal>
```

I've defined form submition on the `saveColumn` button and it works almost as needed. It does submit the form and yes, it does close the modal. What it doesn't do is validation. The `<Input>`'s validation works fine, but only when I'm actually focused on the `<Input>`. The
`<Select>`'s validation doesn't trigger at all. I can open the modal, not even attempt to write anything, trigger form submition on `saveColumn` button click and it still won't react at all. I was tempted (and did try just that) to move the buttons into the actual form and remove the buttons from the modal footer but the client did not like that and so I'm stuck with this. What am I doing wrong? Or is this just a massive pile of garbage that should be disgarded?

The StyleImports is just a collection of all the `styled-component` elements I have imported from every `.ts` file where I describe the components and exported for use in the rest of the app as a single unit. Same with JsonImports.

Comment: Since submit button is not inside `Form` component,`form.submit()` will not trigger validation. Validation and submit form only triggers if button is inside form and button has `htmlType="submit"`. You can trigger validation like this: `onClick={async () => { try { await form.validateFields(); form.submit(); setColumnDetailsModalOpen(false); } catch (e) {} };}`

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot. I wouldn't have thought of that. As far as I was knew before asking this question, Ant automatically performed form validation on submittion (aka form.submit()).

Comment: If obviously performs field validation if you call `form.submit()` from anywhere, `form.validateFields()` is unnecessary. Just make sure you pass the form instance to the form component `<Form form={form} />`.